# python XPath for peoplefinders.com missing text items

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, jupyter

I am trying to scrape data from peoplefinders.com. But the parts I want to retrieve are returning empty.

```
page = requests.get("http://www.peoplefinders.com/peoplesearch/searchresults?search=People&fn=joe&mn=&ln=jackson&city=&state=&age=&dobmm=&dobdd=&doby=1955")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
page.headers['Content-Type'] #'text/html; charset=utf-8'

tree.xpath('//a[@class = "reporttextblue"]') #returns []
```

In html inspection the text part I want goes as:

```
<a class = "reporttextblue" href = "...">
text text text
<span></span> 
text text text
<br/>
text text text  
</a>
```

Notes:

- I run kernels in jupyter notebook.
- I tried both in IE and chrome browsers, but did not work.
- The website is a dynamic one, it changes
  html as ::before and ::after, when you minimize or maximize.
- There are missing text from the website when running:

  tree.xpath('//text()')

I hope that someone might tell me what is the real reason behind this and maybe tell me a better way to scrape that data by using Python.

Thank You

Comment: I can't see elements with `class="reporttextblue"` on mentioned page. Do you mean `class="text-blue name-blue"`?

Answer (score 0):

not sure where that is in the page you mentioned. in the page, those nodes are siblings, and not within the a node. So just use following-sibling to navigate to those nodes.

but for the DOM that you mentioned, try placing an index (ex. /text()[1] or /text()[2]).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there are two views to the same exact page:
1) For loggedin users
2) Other viewers

A simple session.post with authentication info allowed me to get the data I wanted from the beginning.